# How to tell what type of newline is being used in a txt file?

Tags: mysql, newline

I have a txt file which contains quoted, comma deliminated text, and i am trying to figure out what type of newline is being used.

The reason is because i am trying to import it into mysql server, using local infile, and obviously i need to tell it the correct LINES TERMINATED BY

When i use either \n or \r\n it imports exactly half, of the records only, skipping a line each time.

But when i use \r it imports exactly double, giving me the exact number of rows as all values null, as there are records.

When i open the file in notepad, there is no space in between lines, however, if i open it in a browser, there is a blank line in between each line, as though there is a paragraph there somewhere. Like wise if i choose "open with > Excel" it does not put into columns, and has a blank line between each. The only way to open properly in excel is to use "get external data > From text" and choose comma deliminator.

I provide a couple of lines below exactly by just copying and pasting, and obviously it would be great if someone could let me know the correct settings to use for importing. But i it would be even more great, if there was a way for me to quickly know what type of newline any particular file is using (there is also a blank line at the very end of the file as per the other rows).

```
"Item No.","Description","Description 2","Customers Price","Home stock","Brand Name","Expected date for delivery","Item Group No.","Item Group Name","Item Product Link (Web)","Item Picture Link (Web)","EAN/UPC","Weight","UNSPSC code","Product type code","Warranty"

"/5PL0006","Drum Unit","DK-23","127.00","32","Kyocera","04/11/2013","800002","Drums","http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2f5PL0006","http://s.product.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG","5711045360824","0.30","44103109","","3M"

"/DK24","DK-24 Drum Unit FS-3750","","119.00","8","Dell","08/11/2013","800002","Drums","http://uk.product.com/product.aspx?id=%2fDK24","http://s.product.eu/products/2_PICTURE-TAKEN.JPG","5711045360718","0.20","44103109","","3M"
```

Comment: I often use the free Notepad++ editor. Open the file in it and you can toggle to display control characters display.

Comment: Hmm. Adn doing same with your included text, it looks like both a CR and LF. But wondering if your cut and paste may have modded it.

Comment: You can use Notepad++ and do a regular expression search, if each line ends with '\r' or '\n' or '\r\n'

Comment: I downloaded Notepad++ and selected "View > Show symbols > All symbols" At the end of each line it prints CR and in each of the blank rows it prints CRLF What settings should i choose for importing this file using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?